# Refill lives after application exit

Tags: unity, c#

I try to implement refilling lives functionality after exit application. Every live is refilling after 25 minutes, but unfortunately only if the user is in the game. 
Here is the sample code:

```
private void ResetOneLive()
    {
        if (currentLives < MAX_LIVES)
        {
            if (!resetLiveTime.HasValue || DateTime.Now < resetLiveTime.Value)
            {
                if (resetLiveTime.HasValue)
                {
                    TimeSpan remaining = resetLiveTime.Value - DateTime.Now;
                    string timerCountdownText = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}", remaining.Minutes, remaining.Seconds);
                    timeToNextLive.text = timerCountdownText;
                    if (timerCountdownText == "00:00" && resetLive)
                    {
                        this.currentLives += 1;
                        Debug.Log("+1 live");
                        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(PLAYER_PREFS_LIVES, this.currentLives);
                        resetLive = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //for develop purpose set 10 sec
                resetLiveTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
                resetLive = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the game I call this function in `Update()`. I tried to call it `OnApplicationQuit` and `OnApplicationPause` but it does not work.

Can someone tell me how i can implement that functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do more than what you have already. Did you try:

- When the user exits the game, save the time somewhere.
- When the user restarts, look at the time they exited.
- Based on the difference, refill as many lives as necessary.

You can figure out the number of lives with simple math -- if the user refills a life every 10 minutes, and they were gone 53 minutes, they get five lives back.

Comment: You are right it's works.

Comment: @chunk1ty glad I could help. if it answered your question, please click the check-mark next to my answer.